# For $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n \frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}$ where $Q(n)$ and $P(n)$ are polynomials, does di(con)vergence only depends on $z$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Question.** For some series of the form
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n \frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}$$
> where $Q(n)$ and $P(n)$ are polynomials, does di(con)vergence only depends on $z$?

Indeed if we use the root test we have that if

$$ L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(|z^n|\left| \frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}\right| \right)^{1/n}$$

and $L < 1$ then the series converges and if $L > 1$ then diverges.

Now in our case the limit can be rewritten using limit laws as:

$$ |z| \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}\right|^{1/n} \right) = 1$$

Indeed we have that if $|z|<1$ the series converges absolutely and if $|z|>1$ the sum diverges.

But what can be said in case $z = 1, -1$?

It seems to me that if what I wrote so far is correct this kind of series act very much like geometric series, so it should diverge in both cases. But how to prove it since the root test is inconclusive if $L$ is $1$?

Comment: Do you really mean to have two different variables? If so, it's just a simple separable product: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n = \frac{P(x) z}{Q(x) (1-z)}$$

Comment: @aschepler no i didn't, it may be confusing let me fix it

Comment: Note if a sequence does not converge to zero, its infinite series cannot converge at all.

Comment: For large $n$ we know that $P(n)/Q(n)$ behaves like $n^{\deg P -  \deg Q}$ so things should be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $d = \deg Q - \deg P$. Then we may write

$$ \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)} = \frac{R(z)}{z^d} $$

for some rational function $R(z)$ such that $R(z) \to 1$ as $z \to \infty$. This gives a decisive answer for the behavior of the sum along the circle of convergence:

- If $z = 1$, then

  $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^n \frac{P(n)}{Q(n)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{R(n)}{n^d}, $$

  and so, the sum converges absolutely for $d > 1$ and diverges for $d \leq 1$ by the limit comparison test.
- If $|z| = 1$ but $z \neq 1$, then

  $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^n \frac{P(n)}{Q(n)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^n \frac{R(n)}{n^d} $$

  converges absolutely for $d > 1$, converges conditionally for $d = 1$ by the [Dirichlet test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), and diverges for $d < 1$.